# Error in if Condition

Tags: java

i have the three variable int value1,value2 and a String operator. and i want to check the if Condition. suppose value1=4,value2=3 and in operator='>'. then how i check the if condition for Example -

```
int value1=4;
int value2=3;

String operator=">";
if (value1+operator+value2)
{
 System.out.println("hello");
}
i know the this is wrong but how to correct it..
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use the String directly.  You have to check to see what kind of operator it is to begin with, then perform the explicit math operation.

```
public boolean applyOperator(String op, int a, int b) {
    if (">".equals(op)) {
        return a > b;
    } // the others are an exercise to the reader.
}

// later in the code

if(applyOperator(operator, value1, value2)) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way would be to make an `if` statement for each available operator that you expect to use.

```
int value1=4;
int value2=3;

String operator=">";
if(operator.equals(">"))
{
    if(value1 > value2)
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
else if(operator.equals("<"))
{
    // And so on...
}
```

Comment: Great! Can you mark this answer as the solution by clicking the green check to the left?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply give this.

```
if (value1 > value2)
```

Btw, why do you want to give the `operator` in a `String` and then, use that `String` instead of an operator as such? Is there any special requirement for that? In that case, **@Makoto's** answer is a good bet for you.

Answer (score 0):

value1+operator+value2 will be a string only not boolean which is needed in `if`
so instead of `if (value1+operator+value2)` put `if (value1 > value2)`

Answer (score 0):

Compare two integers in java like this:

```
if (value1 > value2) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

You shouldn't be putting the operator into a string.
In java, '+' is used for addition of numbers, and concatenation of strings, not to build expressions.